# Stream file from URL to File without storing it in the memory

Tags: java, android, stream

I want to download a file from a URL and store it into the file system. However I have memory limitation and I don't want to store it in the memory before. I am not a java expert and I am a bit lost with all the class InputStream, BufferedReader, FileOutputStream, etc. Could you help me please ?

For now I have:

```
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
ucon.connect();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
// Create a reader for the input stream.
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

// ?

FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
// Here the content can be too big for the memory...
fos.write(content.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Please, could you give me some clue ? I was thinking also to read it chunk by chunk, but I am not sure what would be the easiest with java...

Comment: `" I am a java expert and I am a bit lost with all the class InputStream, BufferedReader, FileOutputStream..."` -- did you mean to say that you are **not** a Java expert? Because the two parts of this statement don't make sense together.

Comment: Great, thanks. That makes more sense. What kind of "memory limitation" do you have and why? How does your current code not work?

Comment: I am on a android, and I was thinking that these devices must have memory limitations.

Comment: I still don't see why you think that using a BufferedReader (whose buffer size you can set by the way), will take up too much memory. You should have no limitations on use of this.

Comment: I used the method proposed by Sergi0 and it works great (That's what I was thinking when I said 'chunk by chunk'). Sorry for being not so clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File)
```

I guess it may not work on android
I use this code

```
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int cnt = - 1;

OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
while ( (cnt = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
  output.write(buffer, 0, cnt);
}
output.close();
```

Comment: Is this library available on android platform ? If not, is it recommended to include this library ?

Comment: It's generally better to use the version of that method that takes  connectionTimeout and readTimeout parameters - otherwise, you might find that blocking for an unacceptably long time in some situations.